# Why can the array in [Find The Duplicate Number in Array] be "converted into a linkedlist with circle"?

Tags: algorithm

I got a problem on `Finding The Duplicate Number in Array`, here is the question:

---

Given an array of integers nums containing n + 1 integers where each integer is in the range [1, n] inclusive.

There is only one repeated number in nums, return this repeated number.

You must solve the problem without modifying the array nums and uses only constant extra space.

Constraints:

- 1 <= n <= 10^5
- nums.length == n + 1
- 1 <= nums[i] <= n
- All the integers in nums appear only once except for precisely one integer which appears two or more times.

Examples:

- Input: nums = [1,3,4,2,2]
- Output: 2

---

After pondering the question for a while, I thought of a cycle, but I wasn't sure if it would necessarily form one.

After reading the solution, I discovered that Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm could be applied here.

However, I've only used this algorithm when searching for the cycle in linkedlist. The answer just told me that I can get the result by doing this, but it didn't tell me why I could do this. I've always been puzzled by how this array can be "converted into a linkedlist with circle". Could anyone help me to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

The sum of `n` nonrepeative integers `1 <= k <= n` is

`Sn = n * (n + 1) / 2`.

Calculate `S`, the sum of numbers in array `nums`.

`d = S - Sn` is the duplicate number.
Note that `d` should be less or equal to `n`.